# How to input days in time series plot using R?

Tags: r, date, plot, time-series, frequency

I can't input properly the days in a time series. I don't know what's wrong.

```
days <- seq(from=as.Date("2020-02-26"), to=as.Date("2020-04-13"), by="day")
x1 <- rnorm(length(days),3,0.5)
x2 <- rnorm(length(days),6,1.2)
df <- data.frame(days,x1,x2)

df_ts <- ts(df$x1, start=c(2020,1), end=c(2020,48), frequency=365)
df_ts1

>Time Series:
>Start = c(2020, 2) 
>End = c(2020, 4) 
>Frequency = 365 
>[1] 2.682319 3.039276 2.201990
```

The 'Start' and 'End' arguments are right, but the output is wrong `[1] 2.682319 3.039276 2.201990` Then I changed the start and end arguments:

```
df_ts2 <- ts(df$x1, start=c(2020,1), end=c(2020,48), frequency=365)
df_ts2

>Time Series:
>Start = c(2020, 1) 
>End = c(2020, 48) 
>Frequency = 365 
>[1] 2.682319 3.039276 2.201990 3.708056.....................
```

In this case the 'Start' and 'End' arguments are wrong, but the output is right.

Also when I plot it, the X axis is this way: `2020.00 2020.04 2020.08 2020.12`

How can I fix this? I'd like to output the time series with quantity of days or the regular dates.

Answer (score 0):

If you are somewhat flexible with regard to the object class, you might want to consider using the `xts` package.

```
library(xts)

days <- seq(from=as.Date("2020-02-26"), to=as.Date("2020-04-13"), by="day")
x1 <- rnorm(length(days),3,0.5)
x2 <- rnorm(length(days),6,1.2)
df <- data.frame(days,x1,x2)

df_ts <- xts(df$x1, order.by = days)
plot(df_ts)
```